# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'dns' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, angular, import

I have an angular 16 application and I'm trying to import **AnyARecord** from the **dns** node module, but I got the error:

```js
import { AnyARecord } from 'dns';

error TS2307: Cannot find module 'dns' or its corresponding type declarations
```

since I don't have a `webpack` config, I added to `tsconfig.json` this:

```
"module": "Node16",
```

The only available option are `Node16` and `NodeNext`, **node** as an option is not working:

[image]

but when I click on CTRL + the symbol I want to import, I see that it get me to the correct source code!

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

I checked `Typescript` and `Nodejs` compatibility and used `Typescript 5.0.4`, but I got the same error message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're out of luck. [dns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dns) ([github](https://github.com/hbouvier/dns)) is a js lib, and there's no `@types/dns`. So the only thing you can do is include the script through a `<script src="...">` tag, use the code that becomes available, and optionally write some type declarations yourself ([example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player/types/vimeo/index.d.ts) - [tsconfig](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player/tsconfig.lib.json#L8))